# Predicting values in R ( multiple Regression)

Tags: r

I have completed the regression analysis of data which consists of studyhours,examgrade, classhours and sleephours
I would like to know predict the values givenvalues of studyhours, this is sample of what I am coding so far, I got the regression but not the prediction, how can I solve this?

```
> lm.fit


Call:
lm(formula = as.numeric(as.factor(examgrade)) ~ studyhours + classgrade + sleephours, data = mydata)


Coefficients:
(Intercept)   studyhours   classgrade   sleephours  
8.82448     -0.35188    -0.02341    -0.16522
```

This is where it starts to go wrong,

```
> newdata=data.frame(studyhours=(c(5,25,100,150,250)))


> new.studyhours=data.frame(wt=c(5,25,100,150,250))

> predict (examgrades, newdata=new.studyhours)
Error in predict(examgrades, newdata = new.studyhours) :
  object 'examgrades' not found
```

> predict (examgrade, newdata=new.studyhours)
>   Error in predict(examgrade, newdata = new.studyhours) :
>     object 'examgrade' not found

Thanks for any help or guidance.

Comment: I only  was given newdata for study hours....... or can explain a little more thanks

Comment: It is not a duplicate question, I am asking something different...... I saw that question and it didnt help

Comment: I even used the format predict (lm.fit ,data.frame(studyhours=(c(5,10 ,15))),
interval ="confidence ") and it didnt work

Comment: have you tried changing the typo in `predict (examgrades, newdata=new.studyhours)` from `examgrades` to `examgrade` ?